# passing a vector of structs into a function

Tags: c++

In a program the following struct is defined in a header file:

```
\\structs.h
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using namespace std;
struct cell
{
    double x;
    vector<int> nn;
};
```

In a separate source file I define the function:

```
\\functions.cpp
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
# include <stdio.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
# include <vector>
# include "structs.h"
using namespace std;

void initial_position(vector<cell>& cluster, int n)
{
    cell tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tmp.x = 1;
        cluster.push_back(tmp);
    }
}
```

with a header file:

```
//functions.h
# include <vector>
using std::vector;

void initial_position(vector<cell>& cluster, int n);
```

I wish to call this function in the main script:

```
//main.cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include "functions.h"
#include "structs.h"  
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    vector <cell> cluster;
    int n = 100;
    initial_position(cluster,n);
    return 0;
}
```

but get the following errors:

> functions.h(4): error C2065: 'cell': undeclared identifier
>
> functions.h(4): error C2923: 'std::vector': 'cell' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
>
> functions.h(4): error C3203: 'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type
>
> main.cpp(14): error C2664: 'void initial_position(std::vector &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector>' to 'std::vector &'

What is the source of the errors? it all seems to be well defined.

Comment: Add `# include "structs.h"` inside function.h (before the declaration of the problematic function).

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header file? Are you working alone or just want to make people reject your patches?

Comment: @StoryTeller, I don't understand the comment, can u pls explain?

Comment: [It's already explained better, by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Never put "using namespace std" in a header file! std namespace will be accessible every time that file is included, which is very dirty. Find a more detailed explanation in the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file)

Comment: Learn how to use/write header in C++.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just swap

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "structs.h"
```

with

```
#include "structs.h"  
#include "functions.h"
```

Since cell is declared in structs.h and is needed in functions.h

Or better yet, include structs.h in functions.h

You should also not place using namespace std in a header, that is bad practice. It can cause some nasty hard to find bugs, see e.g. [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/1452759)

Comment: `#include`s order should never affect program compilation

Comment: If `functions.h` needs `structs.h`, then it should include that itself. Since C++17, `std::vector` has minimal support for incomplete types, too, so a forward declaration is sufficient as long as the full definition is included before use.

Comment: I agree with you both

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
#include "structs.h"
```

into functions.h and protect both structs.h and functions.h with include-guards, e.g.

```
#pragma once
```

if available.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
#include "structs.h"
```

into functions.h since in functions.h compiler doesn't know what cell is.